# How do I get the actual image taken from a camera in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bitmap

I am taking a photo using the camera in Android Studio and I would like to save the actual image that resulted from the action. I can access the URI just fine but I would like the actual image itself, as I need to send the photo to a database.

```
    var image_uri: Uri? = null
    lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
    
    private fun openCamera() {
        val resolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the Camera")
        image_uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, image_uri)

        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri)
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)
    }
```

I have read that the easiest way to do this is to create a bitmap but I can not get that to work. Running my overall program, the application crashes whenever openCamera is even called. If I comment out the bitmap line, then the function works fine (except I don't have the file saved like I want). How can I do this to where bitmap is an actual Bitmap Object that I can send to the backend of my program?

Comment: The image will not be available to you until your `onActivityResult()` method is called. So, try working with the image then. Note that if your objective is to send the image to a server, loading a `Bitmap` may not be that useful to you, since you have no good way to get that to a server. Instead, [upload the image from the `Uri` directly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get image bitmap from Camera with this way:

```
// Open camera
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
resultLauncher.launch(cameraIntent)

// Get your image
private val resultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (result?.data != null) {
                bitmap = result.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get the Bitmap is in `onActivityResult()` like  `val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap`. I suggest looking at the documentation for camera, maybe you'll find something useful [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#kotlin).

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the actual image would be to pass the file object, you want to store the image at, to the intent - and that is where the full size image will be.

according to [android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics#TaskPath)

you should create the file (assuming you've got the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions depending on the android version and the location of the file you create...) and then pass the file to intent

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        val photoFile: File? = try {
            createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
            null
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        photoFile?.also {
            val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    it
            )
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the code snippet it refers to a method "createImageFile()" where the file is being created (The docs in the link provides some samples).